# Assigning multiple variables from a looping prompt input in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, variables

I'm writing a very simple program, which asks for a number of names depending on how many tickets are needed. I cannot find a way to change the variable that the prompt input is assigned to every time the loop runs. Is there a way to do this? Below is the current loop I'm using.

```
while (ticketsNeeded != 0) {
        name = prompt("Enter the name of attendee #" + ticketsNeeded);
        ticketsNeeded--;
    }
```

For example, if three tickets are needed, the user will be prompted for three different names; however, they are all saved to the same variable and I'd like to have them uniquely assigned so I can later use them.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: use arrays to store multiple values

Answer (score 0):

An array will solve your problem:

```
var names = []; // initialize empty array
var ticketCounter = 0;
while (ticketsNeeded != 0) {
        names[ticketCounter++] = prompt("Enter the name of attendee #" + ticketsNeeded);
        ticketsNeeded--;
    }
```